# Issues inserting an element to an array when the index is at the end and an empty array

Tags: c++

First time posting something here. Hope I'm doing it right.
If not let me know.

Here's the issue:
I'm trying to insert an element into a given array.

I added a for loop that checked to see if the numOfElem was equal to zero then a[0] would equal elem, but that didn't help either.

```
void insertAtIndex(int a[], int numOfElem, int elem, int index)
{
    for (int i = numOfElem; i > index; i--)
    {
        a[i] = a[i-1];
    }
    a[index] = elem;
    numOfElem++;
}
```

Test Cases:

## 1:

Initial Array: No elements in the array.
Insert 10 at index 0...
Modified array: No elements in the array.

## 2:

Initial Array: 1
Insert 20 at index 0...
Modified array: 20
/*As you can see here it added the 20 to the correct index, but it deleted the 1 instead of shifting it to the right.*/

## 3

Initial Array: 3
Insert 30 at index 1...
Modified array: 3
/*It did nothing to this test case. Whenever the element that has to be added is at the end it does not add it, it returns the initial array with no change.*/

In summary, whenever the index of the element that I​ want to insert would be at the end of the modified array or the array is empty it will not make any changes to the array.

Any tips/advice help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: how do you create the array?

Comment: `numOfElem++` - it seems someone needs to learn the chapter about functional arguments and local variables.

Comment: You might have an off-by-one problem here (caused by arrays in C counting from 0), but that is hard to tell if you do not provide a [mcve].

Comment: Hi Yaxer98. You definitly need to make a [mcve] to get a decent answer. The one below for example lists some problems which are based on assumptions on how you use this function. Some of them are not necessarily true. With a mostly matching environment and use of this function, the only problem you end up having would be that the count of stored elements is not updated outside of your funciton. So please show how you use it. @Armin might be right with their asssumptions, but others will only answer if you make a MCVE/MRE; and those answers could/would be more to the point of your situation.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with the given example.

- You tagged the question with C++, but it is pure C code (see also below)
- You are using plain C-Style arrays
- You should use C++ STL containers
- You need to understand how to pass parameters to a function
- You nee to read about the "decay to pointer" topic
- You must understand how indices in arrays are counted

The last bullet point is the reeason why your program does not work. Array indices start with 0. So, if you have an array with 3 elements, valid indices are 0,1,2. And NOT and under NO ciumstances 3.

So, if your `index` is equal to `numOfElem` you will write to an out of bounds memeory area with `a[i] = a[i-1];`. This is a major bug and may lead to a catastrophy.

Then, you pass parameter `numOfElem` by value. Meaning, the compiler makes a copy of this variable and uses the copy in the function. `numOfElem++;` will work on a local copy and will not increase the variable. A good compiler will warn you. This statement is a "no operation". Please always compile wit ALL warnings enables.

And I hope, but cannot see it, that you do not expect your array to grow dynamically by incrementing a variable.

Many STL containers have `insert` functions that will do the job.

Comment: The helpful and assumption-free part of this is "`numOfElem++;` will work on a local copy and will not increase the variable". But that is not your really your mistake. You probably are honestly mislead by your assumptions. Try to reverse your assumptions from "everything OP did is wrong" to "most of what OP did could be correct". The MCVE, which you are assuming instead of requesting, would then look differently and have only the single problem of the element count not being updated. If you make your own question "What is the smallest set of made errors around this code?" I could elaborate.